# In MVC5 how can I create user records in code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-identity, httpcontext

VS2013, MVC5, VB

The MVC5 template works well to create new users from the Register View while the application is running.  But if I want to create users in code, how do I do that?

The following is naïve code, but demonstrates what doesn't work:

```
Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {.UserName = "name@live.com", .Email = "name@live.com"}
Dim acct As New AccountController
acct.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "Temp1.11")
```

This doesn't work because there is no HttpContext for UserManager.

There's a lot going on here that I don't understand and I'm a little lost.  What I set out to do was simply create a list of users using the seed method in Configuration.vb.  I thought I could just copy the way the existing AccountController.Register method works, but obviously not.

The answer to my question would ultimately be how to create users in the seed, but I'd like to also understand why my thinking was so wrong about simply trying to use portions of the code from the Register method.  I don't quite understand the HttpContext and how that comes into being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `AccountController` to get access to the `UserManager` object. Instead just create that directly:

```
Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {.UserName = "name@live.com", .Email = "name@live.com"}
Dim myUserManager As New UserManager()
myUserManager.CreateAsync(user, "Temp1.11")
```

Comment: OK, that was intense.  Although in my project your answer above did not work exactly as written, your suggestion to create UserManager directly was important for me - thx.  So instead of your 2nd line above I used:  "Dim myUserManager = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext))"  Even though it worked, I don't really understand what is happening in the line of code I used, and I hate that.  So I will post a different question to ask about it.  Again, thx!