# What is the syntax for creating an instance of UserManager actually doing?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

VS2013, MVC5, VB

I was helped to solve a problem for creating users in my seed method for an MVC5 application at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801063/in-mvc5-how-can-i-create-user-records-in-code/28801187#28801187).

This question is to ask what is going on with this line of code that is working correctly:

```
Dim myUserManager = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext))
```

The following is to explain what I don't understand.  I will break this down into what I understand, and then follow with what I don't understand.

```
New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)... is creating an instance of UserManager, yes?
```

After that, there are 2 more 'new things'

```
... (New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext))
```

I don't understand that syntax.  There's an overall parenthesis that holds inside a new UserStore followed by another set of parenthesis for a new context.

That's the part I don't follow.  Part of my lack of understanding is (1) what that type of syntax means in general, and the other part is (2) why that syntax is required in this situation.

What is the "New UserStore" for, and then the "New" phrase after that?

Is there a longer way to write this that is more explanatory?

Comment: It's called [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx). I would suggest you split this line into 3 (one line for each new), it might help you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like maybe you don't understand the generic type parameters being used in the statement ([this may help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx)).  Not sure if this will help, but you could break it down like this:

```
' Create an instance of ApplicationDbContext.
' The parens were missing in the original.
Dim context = New ApplicationDbContext()
' Create an instance of the generic type UserStore(Of T), with
' ApplicationUser as the type parameter, T.
' The type of userStore is therefore UserStore(Of ApplicationUser).
' context is passed as a parameter to the constructor.
Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(context)
' Create an instance of the generic type UserManager(Of T), with
' ApplicationUser as the type parameter, T.
' The type of myUserManager is therefore UserManager(Of ApplicationUser).
' userStore is passed to the constructor as a parameter
Dim myUserManager = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(userStore)
```

Comment: Or... what Steven said!  I type too slow.

Comment: Well, I was too slow too because you beat me to the generic types part, so +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

The following line of code:

```
Dim myUserManager = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext))
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
Dim myApplicationDbContext As New ApplicationDbContext
Dim myUserStore As New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(myApplicationDbContext)
Dim myUserManager = New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(myUserStore)
```

1. The first step is to create a new `ApplicationDbContext` object, which takes no arguments to its [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z08e49e(v=vs.90).aspx).
2. The second step is to create a new `UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)` object, which takes the already created `ApplicationDbContext` object as an argument to its constructor.
3. The third step is to create a new `UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)` object, which takes the already created `UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)` object as an argument to its constructor.

The `(Of ...)` part of the type name is a generic parameter.  .NET supports [generic types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w256ka79(v=vs.100).aspx).  The part after `Of` is a type parameter to the generic class.  So, just as `Dim x As New List(Of String)` creates a list of strings, `UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)` creates a user-store for storing application-users.

Comment: Got it!  I see now the initial code I used is a shortcut to build up the necessary components for the New UserManager to be constructed.  One follow-up if I can: the last line of your 'equivalent' code has "New x(of y)(z), which is actually also like the 2nd line.  The (z) at the end of the line; is that just a standard type of syntax for certain methods to pass in needed components and for some reason has to be done differently than passing  components inside the parenthesis?  On the links you gave, none of those showed that type of parenthesis syntax for passing a component in.

Comment: BTW, how do you mark 2 answers? I looked at SO Help but couldn't figure it out.  Both of you helped me.

Comment: @Alan That's a parameter to a constructor.  Classes can create optional, or even required parameters on their constructors.  When they do, you can (or must) pass the parameters within parenthesis after the type name, like that, when you create a new object.  For instance,  `Dim p As New Point(1, 2)` creates a new `Point` object where its coordinates are x = 1 and y = 2.

Comment: @Alan You cannot mark more than one question as the correct answer.  You have to pick whichever one was most helpful to you.  If multiple answers are helpful, you can up-vote all of them, but you can only mark one as the correct one, though.  You may need more reputation points, though, before you can up-vote answers.  If both answers were equally helpful to you, pick Mark's answer, since he needs the points more than me :)

Comment: Notice how the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `Point` structure shows three different overloads for the constructor.  The one I was using in the example in my previous comment was the `Point(Int32, Int32)` one (the third one in the list).